# display alternating urls based on date

Tags: php, html

I am currently working on an advent calendar for my sister. I made a html page with links to the respective pages for each day. The problem is, I do not want her to be able to access all of them at once.

I tried writing a php script:

```
<?php
 $day = date(j);
 if ($day = 1) {
    echo
    '<a href="Days/1.html" id="1">
      <div class="box">
       <h2>1</h2>
      </div>
    </a>';}else{
    echo
    '<a href="Days/error.html" id="1">
       <div class="box">
        <h2>1</h2>
       </div>
     </a>';}
?>
```

but for whatever reason it just creates total chaos. I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Use `switch` for easy logic to limit the date and the URL that u want available

Comment: `if ($day = 1)` `=` sets a value, use `==` to compare

Comment: @ahoi_prause besides from the problem (which actually is the single =, but using the suggested switch statment might make your code clearer) your sister might be so smart to just change the url to Days/2.html in the browser. You could also add a days.php and limit the output there (and generate an error if the day is to high.
```
 $day = date(j);
 if ($_GET['day'] > $day) {
    // error here
}
// output based on $_GET['day']
```
Open this with /days.php?day=1

Answer (score 1):

If only the URL is changing set that to a `var` and then just use that within the HTML rather than redoing it each time.

**Example**

Set `$url` with a `switch` statement using a fallback default or error url if there is no match.

```
<?php
$url = "";
$day = date("j");
switch($day)
{
    case 1:
        $url = "Url 1";
        break;
    case 2:
        $url = "Url 2";
        break;
    default:
        $url = "Default URL";
        break;
}
?>
```

Update the HTML inline like this

```
<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>" id="1">
    <div class="box">
        <h2>1</h2>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Missing `'` on the date param. Should be `date('j')`. =)

Comment: @cottton Ooops updated :D